# Can't Get ASP.NET MVC Regular Expression Attribute Validation To Recognize Dot Character

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I have this regular expression attribute on a model property:

```
   [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}\.){4,5}([a-zA-Z0-9]{​1,6}){1}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid ID format")]
```

I though I was escaping the dot character but I don't get a match when I enter a valid data pattern.

aa.aa.aa.aa.aa

When I change the \. to something else like -(hyphen), I can get a match.

What do I have to change to get the expression to recognize the dot character?

**Update**

Here's what the markup looks like:

```
<input name="Builder.EnvisionOrgID" class="text-box single-line input-validation-error" id="Builder_EnvisionOrgID" type="text" value="HA" data-val-required="The Envision Org ID field is required." data-val="true" data-val-regex-pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}\.){4,5}([a-zA-Z0-9]{​1,6}){1}$" data-val-regex="Invalid ID format">
```

Comment: Works fine [here](http://www.regexr.com/3ecq7)

Comment: Works fine for me too there but not in my ASP.NET MVC page :(

Comment: Just viewed the source for this page and you have a non-breaking white space character in the regex? Is that being rendered in your view as well?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the markup output to my question.

Comment: That's what I get also and it works fine for me - "aa.aa.aa.aa.aa" is valid and does not generate a validation error

Comment: @Stephen Yes, in the second expression ([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}){1} there is an invisible character. I don't know where.

Comment: After reading the comments. I hand typed the RegEx in as I had cut and pasted it initially. What do you know? It is now working! If anyone wants to write up an answer, I will mark it as working, Thanks all.

Comment: The I assume it was the non-breaking space character in your regex (if you right click on the code snippet above and click _Inspect_ you will see a `&#8203;` in the value)